# How to join tables based on "Calculated Fields" in Tableau?

Tags: join, tableau-api

In order to join one of my tables to other tables, I had to use Calculated Fields to make the field format same as others. However, when I want to join the tables, the new field name created by Calculated Fields does not appear. 
I know that I can export modified data, and import it again to solve the problem, but I'm interested to know if there is a simpler way to do so in Tableau.

Comment: Calculated fields are not written back to your data source. But perhaps you could Blend, not join, on it. Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can not join in the data model using calculated field. If your data is not too large, you can make the join in Tableau by using data blending. Alternatively, create a view or views with the calculated field in the source SQL database.